# Derive from JS RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a third-party JS library. It expects some RegExp as input, which will be used for matching parts of a string. Now I need to use a lookbehind in the RegExp I pass, but lookbehind is not implemented in JS RegExp. So as workaround, I try to derive from RegExp:

```js
function SubRegExp(pattern, matchIndex) {
    this.matchIndex = matchIndex;
    this.prototype = new RegExp(pattern);
    this.exec = function(s) {
      return [ this.prototype.exec(s)[this.matchIndex] ];
   }
}
```

I'm testing it like this:

```js
var re = new SubRegExp('m(.*)', 1);
console.log(re.exec("mfoo"));
console.log("mfoo".match(re));
```

What I get is:

```js
["foo"]
["o", index: 2, input: "mfoo"]
```

The first output is as expected, but I don't really get what is happening with the second output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So that `String.prototype.match` function works with your custom class instance, you should implement a `toString` method, which return regexp string.

```
function SubRegExp(pattern, matchIndex) {

    this.pattern = pattern;
    this.matchIndex = matchIndex;
    this.rgx = new RegExp(pattern);

    this.exec = function(s) {
      return [ this.rgx.exec(s)[this.matchIndex] ];
   }


}

SubRegExp.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.pattern;
}

var re = new SubRegExp('m(.*)', 1);
console.log(re.exec('mfoo'));
console.log('mfoo'.match(re));

//-> ["foo"]
//-> ["mfoo", "foo", index: 0, input: "mfoo"]
```

To explain what happens in your example, and why you get `'o'` as a result. It is, actually, really fun coincidence - `'mfoo'.match(re)` converts `re` instance to string, which then used as a regex pattern. `re.toString() === "[object Object]"`.

`"[object Object]"` - this is a group in regular expression, that's why the first `'o'` is matched :)

**edit**

Sorry, was not too attentive towards second output. `.match()` does not calls your custom `exec` function, as raw regexp string is used (*that from `toString` comes, as I explained*). The only way out is to override the `match` function, though it is not a good practice.

```
(function(){ 
    var original = String.prototype.match;
    String.prototype.match = function(mix) { 
        if (mix instanceof SubRegExp)
            return mix.exec(this);
        return original.call(this, mix);
    }
}());
```

Comment: This answer explains what is happening, but it does not solve the problem. The second call still returns the whole matching string as first match, instead of just the first submatch.